# Google Assistant request permission

Tags: permissions, actions-on-google

Is it possible to send multiple rich response messages, the first featuring content, while the second requests permission?

As it stands now, if I only send one rich response requesting permission, it functions as expected.

However, if I return a rich message with content, along with a second rich response message that requests a permission, only the "optContext" value is displayed, not the prompt for the permission.

Answer (score 0):

You can learn about the exact types of responses you can present to the user [here](https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/responses).

As it says on that page, you can send either a simple response or a rich response. 
A rich response can contain

> At most one basic card, option interface (list or carousel), or StructuredResponse (i.e. You cannot have both a basic card and an option interface at the same time)

This means it is not possible to present your user with two rich responses all at once. A way to solve this is to have some user interaction between the two responses.

Comment: How does SystemIntent play into this though?  That is where the permission request is set. So i have a RichResponse but also have SystemIntent set to request a users location, only the permission request is mentioned, while the RichResponse (SimpleResponse) is not spoken (or displayed).